# IPV6_PKTINFO for GRE tunnel interface

Tags: linux, sockets, ipv6

Does IPV6_PKTINFO work for sockets bound to a tunnel interface ?, I have individual sockets bound to both physical and GRE Tunnel interfaces. cmsg is empty when the packet is received on the GRE tunnel interface. Can anyone please let me know if I am missing anything here ?

Comment: Please take the [introductory tour](http://www.stackoverflow.com/tour). You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too.

Comment: You should be able to see packet information for all incoming IPv6 traffic, you may wish to consider asking the question why your particular configuration is not functioning as expected, and provide details how you tested and verified the situation.  For example is there a defect with the interface you are using?